# Selecting image from StackPanel C# UWP (Adding action listener to UIElement and Image to UIElement)

Tags: c#, uwp, actionlistener, stackpanel, uielement

I am using C# and I am creating UWP app.
I am using Windons.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Image and I have created follwoing code which lists my images

```
UxHelpers.DispatchToASTAThread(
async () =>
{
    imageIndex++;
    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    stackPanel.Children.Add(image);           
}
this.Results.Children.Add(stackPanel);
 }).Forget();
```

This is in for loop, and I want when user clicks on certain image to be able to save it.

I have code for saving, I just don't know how to add mouse listener to each image, so that it is marked when I move mouse over it (So user knows that by clicking on it something will happen) and when he clicks I want it to call my function with this pictures index....

I have looked at UIElement but i still can't figure it out.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add the `PointerEntered` event to the `Image` control that when the user move mouse over it then we can change the UI. Then we can add the `Tapped` event to the `Image` control, if the user click on it, it will be fired.

To get the index of the `Image`, we can set the index to the `Name` property of the `Image`.

For example:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream random = await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/sun2set.jpg")).OpenReadAsync();
        Image image = new Image();
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        StackPanel mystackPanel = new StackPanel();
        image.Name = i.ToString();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(random);
        image.Source = bitmapImage;
        mystackPanel.Children.Add(image);
        image.PointerEntered += Image_PointerEntered;
        image.PointerExited += Image_PointerExited;
        stackPanel.Children.Add(mystackPanel);
    }
    this.Results.Children.Add(stackPanel);
}

private void Image_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;

    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(image) as StackPanel;
    parent.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    parent.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
    image.Tapped -= Image_Tapped;
}

private void Image_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    Debug.WriteLine("The" + image.Name + "is Selected!");
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(image) as StackPanel;
    parent.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    parent.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
    image.Tapped += Image_Tapped;
}

private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    //download the image
}
```